# How to configure multiple web site with django and tornado?

Tags: django, nginx, tornado

On my VDS I use nginx, django and tornado. I had just one project, Now i gonna deploy another one project with a different domain name. I want to use different databases and folders.
I know how to configure nginx for serving static resourses , but what about tornado?
Should i run separeted instance of tornado for each project or is there any better solution?

Comment: Clarifying my question. I wanted to deploy several django projects and  use just **1** serving process. Projects had not many visitors.
For tornado I hadn't found any solution. But for uWSGI, there is [some solution](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/VirtualHosting)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, generally you have to use separate Tornado instances (processes with separate port) for different projects and use different upstream servers for **proxy_pass** directives of each domain in nginx config.